# Быстрая сортировка двумерного массива си

Tags: c, массивы

Я так понимаю это алгоритм быстрой сортировки одномерного массива. Помогите пожалуйста написать для двумерного

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>
void q_sort(int *numbers, int left, int right) 
{
    int pivot, l_hold, r_hold;
    l_hold = left;
    r_hold = right;
    pivot = numbers[left];
    while (left < right) 
    {
        while ((numbers[right] >= pivot) && (left < right))
            right--;
        if (left != right) 
        {
            numbers[left] = numbers[right];
            left++;
        }
        while ((numbers[left] <= pivot) && (left < right))
            left++;
        if (left != right) {
            numbers[right] = numbers[left];
            right--;
        }
    }
    numbers[left] = pivot;
    pivot = left;
    left = l_hold;
    right = r_hold;
    if (left < pivot)
        q_sort(numbers, left, pivot - 1);
    if (right > pivot)
        q_sort(numbers, pivot + 1, right);
}
int main() 
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a[10];
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % 100;
    printf("Elements: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    q_sort(a, 0, 9);
    printf("\n");
    printf("qsort elements: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: что значит "сортировка двумерного массива"? Какой компаратор?

Comment: Как именно вы хотите отсортировать двумерный массив? Каков критерий его отсортированности?

Comment: Просто отсортировать по возрастанию методом быстрой сортировки